# Display counter prop, when mapping to display component in react.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array, with custom Emoji objects, which I'm mapping through to display in my JSX code.

I have  handler, where a user can add an emoji, and will increment a counter, each time it is selected.

```
addEmoji = (newEmoji) =>{
// mark if new emoji is already in the array or not
let containsNewEmoji = false;

// recreate emojis array
let newEmojis = this.state.emojis.map(emoji => {
  // if emoji already there, simply increment count
  if (emoji.id === newEmoji.id) {
    containsNewEmoji = true;

    return { 
      ...newEmoji,
      ...emoji,
      count: emoji.count + 1,
    };
  }

  // otherwise return a copy of previos emoji
  return {
    ...emoji
  };
});
```

I imported the Emoji component, from the emoji-mart node module, and mapping the:

```
 <div className="emoji">
        {this.state.emojis && 
        this.state.emojis.map( (emoji, index) =>{
        return(
         <Emoji key={index} onClick={this.addEmoji} tooltip={true}
        emoji={{id: emoji.id, skin: 1}} size={25}  />
        )
        })  
        }
        </div>
```

how can I display the counter variable, next to the Emoji, to see how many times it has been displayed?

Answer (score 2):

You can a create a component called `EmojiCount` to you'll pass emoji and count as props

```
const EmojiCount = (props)  => {
  return (
      <Emoji {...props.emoji} />
      <div>{props.count}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Should i pass The rendered component in as props?